# Ice cream sandwich tablet saying the internal SD card was removed?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, internal-sd

I just got this tablet, and I was playing on it. Out of nowhere, it said SD card removed. The only problem is it's an internal SD card. So I didn't remove it. Now, it says there is no memory on it. Anyone else have this problem, and know how to fix it?

Comment: Seems like a case for warranty to me. You might try doing a factory reset to see if it helps. Also specifying make and model would help.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly did happen there for that to occur?

The only way this can happen is by going into Settings > Storage, scroll down to the bottom and it says "*Unmount SD Card*", at this point it is already unmounted so that would show by now the following "*Mount SD Card*"?